# When building a cloud function with retries enabled, how can I implement an incremental back-off?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I am trying to build a google cloud function that loads data into an API.  Their guides show examples on how to avoid infinite retries (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries#functions-tips-retry-node6), but I can't find a guide explaining how to implement an incremental backoff.

If the API goes down the GCP function seems to retry as fast as possible.  The ideal option would be to have an increasing delay as the retry count increases.

Does anyone have code examples (node) to implement this?  If not code an explanation or plan of attack would also help.

Researched the docs to no avail.

Comment: Cloud Functions internally manages the retry frequency.  It will determine the backoff.  You currently don't have any control over how that works.

Comment: @Doug - do you have any document explaining how this works ?

Answer (score 1):

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries#set_an_end_condition_to_avoid_infinite_retry_loops

```
 /**
 * Background Cloud Function that only executes within
 * a certain time period after the triggering event
 *
 * @param {object} event The Cloud Functions event.
 * @param {function} callback The callback function.
 */
exports.avoidInfiniteRetries = (event, callback) => {
  const eventAge = Date.now() - Date.parse(event.timestamp);
  const eventMaxAge = 10000;

  // Ignore events that are too old
  if (eventAge > eventMaxAge) {
    console.log(`Dropping event ${event} with age ${eventAge} ms.`);
    callback();
    return;
  }

  // Do what the function is supposed to do
  console.log(`Processing event ${event} with age ${eventAge} ms.`);
  callback();
};
```

It seems as if the function will always be retried forcibly. You can however make sure the actual important part of the function is called in a backoff interval.

Just do the following:

```
if(eventAge < 1000 && eventAge > 0)
{
   //Do stuff
}else if (eventAge < 3000 && eventAge > 1000) {
   // Do stuff
}(...)
else{
 return;
}
```

This way your actual code will only be executed in the intervals you set via logic.

Comment: Where does the pause come in?  Will this just continually re-run the function until the timing condition is met?

I've thought about adding a timeout into the function, but this seems inefficient.

I guess it could work if I can pass # of retries to the next call.

Comment: Yeah thats the idea. As long as you have your actual logic inside the retry blocks you dont have to worry about infinite retries on your actual code. Let google retry as long as they want lol

Comment: SetTimeout could work but if the function actually fails on some other uncaught error it wont retry

Comment: Actually, this wouldnt make sure its only called ONCE every interval. The function will probably be called continuesly until the range of each condition is not met anymore. Which means it would be something like this: 5 calls in the first second....3 calls after 3 seconds, 7 calls after 10 seconds etc. Not exactly sure how to fix that problem though

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the  official documentation that you reviewed. You could try to take a look at this document [1] even though it's specify for Cloud IoT Core. You will find different examples depend of you runtime environment. This may help to illustrate how exponential back-off can be implemented.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/exponential-backoff

Comment: So this specifies how to handle it when calling out to google, but not when calling from a google function.  It leverages setTimeout which is a bad practice with FaaS.  More so, it uses in memory counters for the retries where GCP functions are shut down and then rerun for each retry.  Not sure how this could be leveraged.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the docs for [GCS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/exponential-backoff), there's a pretty good explanation about truncated exponential backoff.

However, more interestingly, it states:

> Google Cloud Client Libraries for Node.js can automatically use
>   backoff strategies to retry requests with the autoRetry parameter.

So, digging on any random `@google-cloud` library and looking for that option, we get directed to [this piece of code](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-common/blob/v0.32.1/src/util.ts#L649) handling the retires.

Since that code is under the [Apache License 2.0](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-common/blob/v0.32.1/LICENSE), I'm assuming you could just copy that snippet of code, as long as you abide by the license limitations.

Comment: That documentation is for Google Cloud Storage. The question was about Cloud Functions.

Comment: @aldel The docs were found in the GCS section, but the exponential backoff is a concept that applies everywhere, no matter where you find the explanation to it. Furthermore, if you bothered to follow the link in the answer, there is a full implementation in Node which is not related to any specific API.